# Script no longer lauches target program after new line inserted

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I have a script that basically starts a program like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /path/to/my/program
./muh_program
```

I inserted the following line right above the line begins with "cd":

```
ps -ef | grep muh_program | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

it stopped working.

Why and how do I solve it?

Comment: What is the name of the script? Does the name contain `muh_program`? (e.g. `muh_program_launcher`).

Comment: Take a look at `man pgrep`.

Comment: Note that your inserted line would also kill any editor that happened to have a file open whose name contains `muh_program`, or any other process with `muh_program` in its command line. This would be particularly worrisome if this script was exectued by the root user. Do consider investigating `pkill` instead.

Comment: I did an edit: I think the following code is THE line; we are not discussing an abstract line. Did I get it right? (May be not it took me 2 minutes to find a meaning to the `ps` line, so hope it is the correct one.) It not then it needs editing for clarity.